# Performance Optimisation in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, database, menu

i am creating a site, which is a Library Management system, here there are 2 types of user, `Host (SuperUser), Faculty`. Now i want to show up menus, these menu should be based on the user logged in, like if SuperUser has logged in, he should be able to see everything, whereas if Faculty has logged in, he/she should be able to see only his/her details, now here i have  `3`thoughts:

1. To generate the menu based on the User, from the Database. i mean i would be saving the menu-items in the database and would fetch the menus based on the user logged in

   Directly code in page so as to enable disable the menu-item based on the user logged in.

   To generate xml file containing the menus as per user, and fetching menus from there as per the user logged in.

As i want more performance optimisation from my site, which technique would save me performance, or is there any other best way to populate menu's with ease and performance.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a SiteMap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428(v=VS.100).aspx.  It can handle Roles.